# Windows installer MSI format

Tags: windows-installer

I cannot find the MSI format specification. It says that its an open standard, but I don't see any documentation - just bits and pieces of information here and there.

I want to modify some .msi installer, but I want to understand first what it is doing.

Comment: The MSI file format is undocumented, where did you read it's an open standard?

Comment: An MSI file is a SQL database in a COM structured storage file, and the latter is essentially a file system in a file (file streams).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you got a misunderstanding of Microsoft's promise.

> Open Specification Promise
>
> Published: September 12, 2006. Revised: February 15, 2007
>
> Microsoft irrevocably promises not to assert any Microsoft Necessary
>   Claims against you for making, using, selling, offering for sale,
>   importing or distributing any implementation to the extent it conforms
>   to a Covered Specification (“Covered Implementation”), subject to the
>   following. This is a personal promise directly from Microsoft to you,
>   and you acknowledge as a condition of benefiting from it that no
>   Microsoft rights are received from suppliers, distributors, or
>   otherwise in connection with this promise. If you file, maintain or
>   voluntarily participate in a patent infringement lawsuit against a
>   Microsoft implementation of such Covered Specification, then this
>   personal promise does not apply with respect to any Covered
>   Implementation of the same Covered Specification made or used by you.
>   To clarify, “Microsoft Necessary Claims” are those claims of
>   Microsoft-owned or Microsoft-controlled patents that are necessary to
>   implement only the required portions of the Covered Specification that
>   are described in detail and not merely referenced in such
>   Specification. “Covered Specifications” are listed below.
>
> This promise is not an assurance either (i) that any of Microsoft
>   issued patent claims covers a Covered Implementation or are
>   enforceable or (ii) that a Covered Implementation would not infringe
>   patents or other intellectual property rights of any third party. No
>   other rights except those expressly stated in this promise shall be
>   deemed granted, waived or received by implication, exhaustion,
>   estoppel, or otherwise.

The full list of the open specifications can be found at

http://www.microsoft.com/openspecifications/en/us/programs/osp/default.aspx

Since MSI is not listed within, you can safely assume that it is a private standard and won't be shared to general public.

Comment: Yet there are some 3rd party products which can create and modify .msi files

Comment: Those 3rd party companies may have agreements with Microsoft where they pay for additional support and information.

Comment: Virtually all these 3rd party products use the public Microsoft APIs to read/write MSI files. It's all included in the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 15):

The binary format is not open, I wouldn't even go as far as calling it a standard.

However I assume it's not the file format you're concerned with (which is undocumented), but rather the tables, actions, sequences, etc. that are visible when interfacing with the MSI via the Windows Installer SDK, API, Orca, etc.

Everything is covered in the SDK documentation, however for some reason search engines don't rank the documentation very highly. Also you can no longer download the Windows Installer SDK separately, it is now bundled as part of the Windows SDK.

- [Windows Installer SDK Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688(VS.85).aspx)
- [Windows SDK Download](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

MSI files are COM structured storage, which is described here: [Structured Storage (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

The MSI file format is **not** open and is in fact undocumented, however the API required to access these files is part of the [Windows Installer SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  That link describes both the API functions required to access and modify MSI databases (files), and the contents of the tables in an MSI database.

That said if you want to modify or view the contents of an MSI then the easiest way to do it is probably just to use an editor that someone else has made (which will in turn use these functions).  The ones that I know of are:

- [ORCA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905)
- [InstEd](http://www.instedit.com/)
- InstallShield also have an MSI editor

If you really want to know more about the details of the internals of the MSI file format then take a read through of these two blog articles by Rob Mensching (the author of WiX)

- [Inside the MSI file format](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2003/11/25/inside-the-msi-file-format)
- [Inside the MSI file format, again](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2004/2/10/inside-the-msi-file-format-again)

Comment: The MSI file format is a COM-structured storage file containing a MS-SQL database and associated file streams.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has published the MSI file format details. You can download the specifications for the various versions here: [[MS-CFB]: Compound File Binary File Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cfb/53989ce4-7b05-4f8d-829b-d08d6148375b)

The latest version at the time of this writing is 9.0, released on 9/12/2018. You can download it as a PDF [here](https://winprotocoldoc.blob.core.windows.net/productionwindowsarchives/MS-CFB/%5bMS-CFB%5d.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that .MSI database format is required to modify some installer? Have you heard about the Orca tool? If not, this MS KB article is for you:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905

Comment: I'm using Orca to modify the file. It is great, but that's not the point - sometimes I can guess what is the meaning of each parameter, sometimes I cannot. What I'm looking for is the specification that defines how Windows Installer uses parameters from .MSI database to install the software

Answer (score 2):

In my work with MSI this link [Windows Installer Tools & Tips](http://installsite.org/pages/en/msi/tips.htm#7zip) was very helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget [MakeMSI](http://dennisbareis.com/makemsi.htm) which is a free app to create MSI files.

Comment: a download link is provided on that page of the official site, scroll down to the *DOWNLOAD MAKEMSI v16.059* header

Answer (score 0):

This may help some people.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal

You can build your own installer builder application, if you go through this and learn the Windows Installer APIs explained here. With the APIs mentioned here you can build your own application that can edit the .msi file also.