# Getting MSI properties python

Tags: python, windows-installer

I have an MSI file that I'm trying to extract some of the parameters specified in the Details tab on the file properties.

I found the [msilib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msilib.html) where SummaryInformation.GetProperty(field) looks like the way to go, but I don't understand how to use it. how do I 'connect' it to that existing MSI file and not one that is being created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The msi file contains both cab files and information in a database format.
See this link for more info about its structre and how to view it: [MSI structure answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951289/windows-installer-msi-format).

I never used the python msilib but by reading the documentation my guess is this:

1. to get the db object, use something like:

   `dbobject = msilib.OpenDatabase(path, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)`
2. if you want something in the [summary info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msilib.html#msilib.SummaryInformation.GetProperty) then you can do something like:

   `info = dbobject.GetSummaryInformation(1)
   prop = info.GetProperty(field)`
3. if the information you need is in one of the db tables then you should do a sql query against it:

   `view = dbobject.OpenView(sql)
   rec = view.Execute(params)
   str_val = rec.GetString(field)`

Comment: I tried about the same also, and it was indeed in the right direction. Thanks!!

Comment: The way to do it is:
'import msilib
 db = msilib.OpenDatabase(msi_path, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_READONLY)
 sum_info = db.GetSummaryInformation(1)
 comments = sum_info.GetProperty(msilib.PID_COMMENTS)'