# How to check a file header structure for identifying a MSI file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a solution where I need to be able to check if the file is of specific types where I cannot trust the extension name of that file.

I'm already able to identify EXE and DLL files and just need the last one to be identified.

currently I do not know how to identify a MSI what in the MSI is different from an EXE and a DLL? Where should I look?

for instance to find a DLL I am doing the following:

```
if ((ntHeader.FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL) != 0)
{
    //If DLL then this returns True Else Return False
    return (ntHeader.FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL) == 8192;
}
```

is there a similar solution to find out if the file is of type MSI ?

**EDIT 1**
this is how I'm doing it now based on the idea of dlatikay

```
private static ulong FIRST_8_BYTES_OF_MSI_FILE =0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE1;

private bool MSICheck(FileStream fileData)
{
    byte[] first8bytes = new byte[8];
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileData))
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(first8bytes, 0, 7);
    }
    ulong sum = BitConverter.ToUInt64(first8bytes, 0);

    //string hexString = BitConverter.ToString(first8bytes);
    bool returnval = sum == FIRST_8_BYTES_OF_MSI_FILE;
    return returnval;
    //D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 First 8 hexadecimal of a MSI package
    //return false;
}
```

however this method fails to call out my test msi file as a msi file so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong ?

**My solution:**

with the guidance of **dlatikay**

```
private static string FIRST_8_BYTES_OF_MSI_FILE = "D0CF11E0A1B11AE1";

private bool MSICheck(FileStream fileData)
{
    byte[] first8bytes = new byte[8];
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileData))
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(first8bytes, 0, first8bytes.Length);
    }

    string sum = BitConverter.ToString(first8bytes).Replace("-",""); ;

    bool returnval = sum.Equals(FIRST_8_BYTES_OF_MSI_FILE);
    return returnval;
    //D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1 First 8 hexadecimal of a MSI package
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: the third argument to `reader.Read` is the count, not the upper bound. make it 8 or `first8bytes.Length` and it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSI file format is a privately specified format of Microsoft. It is really a strange beast, I mean who would take a SQL database, force it into a COM storage format and call that MSI? But that's what it is.

Related: 
[Windows installer MSI format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1951289/1132334)

A clean way would be to reference the [Windows Installer SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and attempt a call to `MsiVerifyPackage` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370508(v=vs.85).aspx)) on the file you suspect to be an MSI, if the call returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` you consider it true.

There is a managed version available for .NET:

```
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

...

if(Installer.VerifyPackage(fullpath))
{
    /* positive. it may still be corrupt,
     * but the API says it is a Microsoft Installer package */
}
```

A more practical, lightweight, and faster approach would be to check for the sequence

```
D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1
```

which distinguishes it from Cerius2 files, which have the same extension.

([Source](https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=MSI&mode=EXT))

Comment: I've updated the question based on your idea's but I'm only a little closer to a solution could you elaborate based on the edit ?