# How to read a msi file and get their property using c++

Tags: c++, linux, windows, windows-installer

I am trying to read a msi file using c++

I tried using Microsoft msi tools. But i need it to run in linux too ,so i can't use the msdn msi tools Win32 tools.

Please do say about other msi tools can be used for both windows and linux

Any ideas for the problem.
Do say about msi tools that can be used for both windows and Linux

Comment: There's [msitools](https://wiki.gnome.org/msitools), though it doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: You can give a try to powershell core.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  That is, what do you want to "read" from an MSI that would be useful? And why Linux (where MSI files are never going to exist on)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951289/windows-installer-msi-format

Comment: @selbie It is for a research purposes. Just want to know it is possible or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows installer MSI format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951289/windows-installer-msi-format)

Answer (score -2):

MSI is a binary file format by Microsoft for installing applications, and it is *not* supported in other operating systems AFAIK.
On Windows, you could use the Win32 APIs to `read` a MSI file and explore its contents. Refer the APIs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/msi/nf-msi-msiopenpackagea).

Comment: By the way. Read the comments to OP, these show an active lack of interest of the author.